# how to strip off the hash fragment from URL when user scrolls away?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, position

I have a page with many tiny boxes all reachable using the URL's #hashFragment

Now, I want to try to set up a script that strips off the hash from the URL, when user continues the navigation (for example when he scrolls down or up, or when the #box goes out the user's viewport... what do you think?)

I want the URL containing the fragment to be sharable, so I don't want to strip off it instantly.

I'm not yet confident with location APIs, so I may need your help

It's possible to implement this behavior in a clean way on most common browsers plus IE7, older androids/safari ?

(no jquery, thanks)

thank you in advance

Comment: Changing the navigation bar (`window.location`) will reload the page. +1 for no jQuery btw

Comment: i think it's possible to do that with replaceState | location.hash

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just utilising the onscroll event?

Maybe something like this...

```
window.onscroll = function (oEvent) {
    window.location.hash ="" 
}
```

Comment: use this for body instead: `window.location.hash =""`

Comment: @Geert-Jan Yeah that looks cleaner.